# What are android batteries PIN type?

Tags: battery, hardware

I'm trying to determine the different PIN types of the batteries used in Android, specifically to those batteries that use flex cable.

For example;

[image]

The image above is a sample of batteries for Xiaomi phones, I'm not sure which models used it but they do have a different PIN type, I assumed that these pin types are universal and are not limited to the Xiaomi brand only.

Comment: They called it FPC Pin or FPC Connector.

Comment: even if connector fit that doesn't mean the pinout is identical